# Ubuntu - Notification and sound

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh, notify-send

I try to get a notification + sound everyday at 16PM.
It's work but after that, i lost sound. I have to restart my computer.

The cron:

```
00 16 * * * /bin/bash /home/user/mynotifications.sh
```

mynotifications.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/spd-say "Hey, it's 16 PM !" -l "fr" -t "male2"
/usr/bin/notify-send -i     /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/256x256/status/trophy-gold.png "Notification title" "Notification message"
```

What's wrong here ?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that a script run from your crontab has no access to your interactive environment.

Comment: I think this has to be reopened. It is not a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question talks about the `$DISPLAY` variable, but this one is related to dbus.